# My bootstrap datepicker's some part looks transparent ,what can be cause

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker. I have a problem about it. When I click on `glyphicon-calendar` icon and open datetimepicker widget, it  looks  transparent in some parts, remaining part of it is normal. What can be the cause?

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <div class='input-group date' name="igunudtl">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id=" iadetarihi " />
                    <span class="input-group-addon ">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar ">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please post a jsfiddle, or at least a screen capture

Comment: please look at this link http://i.hizliresim.com/GkD5RN.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If your datetimepicker ([Eonasdan](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)) appears transparent:

**Change bootstrap-datetimepicker.css:**

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff; /* This is your background color. Copy and Paste this row. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your image it looks like you're missing some styles. Make sure you've include both bootstrap styles as well as the datepicker style sheet `bootstrap-datetimepicker[.min].css`.

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/build/css

If you've include both style sheets and you still have the issue, you likely have something that is overriding the picker's styles.

Try turning on the `debug:true` option which leave the picker open for you to inspect with your browsers dev tools.

Comment: I have both css and i didnt understan other issue.can it be about z-index?

Comment: it's not likely the z-index otherwise the whole thing wouldn't show. You likely have some other CSS that's overriding the BS or the picker styles. If you don't know how to use the browser tools, I'd suggest creating a minimal page or remove styles sheets one by one until you get it to look correct. Then you will find your troublesome CSS.